# How to show time ranges in t-sql where there is a break in time

Tags: t-sql, time, range

Currently I am monitoring the usage of a device.  So every minute the device is in use it will make a log entry on my sql server.  There will be breaks in the time stream when the device isn't in use.  Is there a way to make the output show something like

```
01/01/2020 10:01 - 01/01/2020 10:14
01/01/2020 13:15 - 01/01/2020 13:26
```

Below is an image of what my data looks like right now.

[image: Image of time output now]

Comment: What have you tried, what examples have you looked at (as there are many). Try looking at gaps and islands problems.

Comment: I haven't I'm in the research phase on how to tackle this and I've never seen anything like it before.  Also I'm looking into the gaps and islands issue.

Comment: Please don't be angry with me, but imagine every user initially posting questions at the start of their research phase..

Answer (score 1):

You can use TSQL windowing function [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get what the next timestamp is.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #dataset ;

-- USE Recursive CTE to create a Table #dataset that we can work with
WITH cte 
  AS (
      SELECT GETUTCDATE() AS [DateTime], 1 AS counters, 'device-1' AS device_name
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
          -- Cause a Break at 10th and 15th row
          IIF(cte.counters IN ( 10, 15 ), DATEADD( MINUTE, 10, cte.[DateTime] ), DATEADD( MINUTE, 1, cte.[DateTime] ))
        , 1 + cte.counters
        , cte.device_name
      FROM cte
      WHERE cte.counters < 20
)
SELECT * 
INTO #dataset 
FROM cte ;


-- Now that we have a TestDataSet - Let us Query 
SELECT
    [DateTime]
  , device_name
  , LEAD( [DateTime] ) OVER (PARTITION BY device_name ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS next_DateTime
  , CASE
         -- LEAD( [DateTime] ) OVER (PARTITION BY device_name ORDER BY [DateTime]) is what the next time now 
         WHEN DATEDIFF( MINUTE, [DateTime], LEAD( [DateTime] ) OVER (PARTITION BY device_name ORDER BY [DateTime])) > 1 /*Tollerance*/ THEN
             'break'
         ELSE 'ok' END AS break_check_code
FROM #dataset ;
```

Using Lead `LEAD( DateTime ) OVER (PARTITION BY device_name ORDER BY DateTime)` we are asking for the next `DateTime` of the `device_name` (`PARTITION BY`) controls this and then we define the order using `ORDER BY`

Now that we can get the next `DateTime` of the device, we can use some `CASE` and `DATEDIFF` to check what is the time difference between the current timestamp and the next.

This will result in the following

```
|DateTime               |device_name|next_DateTime          |break_check_code|
|2020-01-30 17:00:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:01:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:01:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:02:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:02:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:03:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:03:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:04:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:04:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:05:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:05:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:06:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:06:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:07:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:07:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:08:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:08:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:09:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:09:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:19:19.483|break           |
|2020-01-30 17:19:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:20:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:20:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:21:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:21:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:22:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:22:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:23:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:23:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:33:19.483|break           |
|2020-01-30 17:33:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:34:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:34:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:35:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:35:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:36:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:36:19.483|device-1   |2020-01-30 17:37:19.483|ok              |
|2020-01-30 17:37:19.483|device-1   |NULL                   |ok              |
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/809fd/1) to run this example